# firebase database rule not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The database rule looks like this

```
{
  "rules": {
      "users": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('uid').val() === auth.uid"
      }
  }
}
```

The user object looks like this:

```
{
  "Eay5XLrspSZgdodEnZTBroStx1w2" : {
    "displayName" : "Todd Bertsch",
    "email" : "toddbertsch@gmail.com",
    "emailVerified" : true,
    "isAnonymous" : false,
    "metadata" : {
      "a" : "1512148002000",
      "b" : "1512148002000",
      "creationTime" : "Fri, 01 Dec 2017 17:06:42 GMT",
      "lastSignInTime" : "Fri, 01 Dec 2017 17:06:42 GMT"
    },
    "photoURL" : "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-PtEgSTI46tI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAMEk/Q0_IktNjsoI/photo.jpg",
    "providerData" : [ {
      "displayName" : "Todd Bertsch",
      "email" : "toddbertsch@gmail.com",
      "photoURL" : "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-PtEgSTI46tI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAMEk/Q0_IktNjsoI/photo.jpg",
      "providerId" : "google.com",
      "uid" : "104351756542406315190"
    } ],
    "providerId" : "firebase",
    "refreshToken" : "AEoYo8t7S_E-GrvHt9LUr9nV9Juzgk47p0otIpGy2Lp96W7VU12FB8n4t-N15_5jTZ60afp4fVp-KaJlS-j49FNi_2T38_Kwr2PhLhsIwpS1FwwYfhXbRlIux96VaGHiQOB2m1qH6KI2W1Je5gVGg8-k9G8DtppGjde8eHNZZW7lJNEvNcJdjeGQ6qAyWC5VqCsSkiCv1KKSnLauICd-yNcW3dK0G_oe7rFwjoDAsMPBQ-_Z-PN_cJdlSfTccQIG8WrjB42VhAPq33faMD2xL1Kv2aHs9IH7ngHmSFoNIQCmPicN_mWIvB-kDSKBU9eOhO9t8Dsma3suhqZiGPttASbPvfDP4ElVJrIGQ78TyU9BEXmUwiqGoa4",
    "role" : "user",
    "uid" : "Eay5XLrspSZgdodEnZTBroStx1w2"
  },
}
```

However an user is able to edit other users data which is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

Though I understand fully but changing it to the waay mentioned here seems to work https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/user-security.html

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        // grants write access to the owner of this user account
        // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The rules are relative to the node you are defining them for.  But in addition since you are using the uid as the key you can just do

```
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
  }
}
```